# how to bind events in the cycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

please help to fix the script.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop

slides = {
    'blue': 'active',
    'red': 'active',
    'green': 'unctive',
    'orange': 'active',
    'navy': 'active'
}


for (i, color) in enumerate(slides.keys()):
    item = tkinter.Button( root,
                    text=color,
                    width=20,
                    height=10,
                    relief='raised',
                    borderwidth=5,
                    bg=color
                )
    item.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: invertItem(i, color))
    item.pack(side='left')

def invertItem(i, color):
    print(i, color)
```

I need to after clicking the button displays the number and name colors. Now for some reason always shows "4 blue"

Answer (score 2):

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

slides = {
    'blue': 'active',
    'red': 'active',
    'green': 'unctive',
    'orange': 'active',
    'navy': 'active'
}

for (i, color) in enumerate(slides.keys()):
    item = tkinter.Button( root,
                    text=color,
                    width=20,
                    height=10,
                    relief='raised',
                    borderwidth=5,
                    bg=color
                )
    item.config(command=lambda i=i, color=color: invertItem(i, color))
    item.pack(side='left')

def invertItem(i, color):
    print(i, color)

root.mainloop()
```

Changes:

- Call `root.mainloop()` after setup widgets.
- Use `command` option instead of `bind`.

  - Add default parameter `i`, `color`. Otherwise, they reference last `i`, `color` of `for` loop.

Comment: but where is the mouse click? :)

Comment: @user3218592, The callback function given to `command` option is called when the button is clicked.